# Error in column when changing data type to Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having an issue while changing the data type of a column to Date datatype.
Issue is some dates are not in the proper date format as shown in the attached image.

**Steps I have appied**

Changed Type with Locale en-US

Changed Type with Locale en-GB

Changed type to Date

Need suggestions to fix this issue

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Why do you have two different formats on the same dataset? Dates such as 1st of February on locale en-GB could be the 2nd of January on locale en-US.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates with locale `en-GB` are always with days greater than 12, you can use this function.

```
(_date as text) =>
let
Step1 = List.Transform(Text.SplitAny(_date,"/"), each Number.FromText(_)),
Step2 = 
        if Step1{0} > 12 
            then Date.FromText(_date,"en-gb") 
        else 
            Date.FromText(_date,"en-us") 

in Step2
```

Otherwise, the are some dates that would have ambiguity, such as the 1st of Feb.

Comment: Issue resolved by selecting French (France) Locale settings. I will also try the suggested solution. Thanks, Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by selecting French (France) Locale settings.